# Adding condition in login

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a symfony2 website ,

I have many companies in database , every company should have his own login page and a dashboard like this :

```
 www.site.com/company1/login ==> www.site.com/company1/dashboard
 www.site.com/company2/login ==> www.site.com/company2/dashboard
```

Question 1 : how can I edit the login function to check if this user is in the companyx before to redirect him ?
Question 2 : After authentication in `namecompany/login` , how it can be automatically redirected to `/namecompany/dashboard` ?

Thank you

Comment: Verify your logged in user to the company and redirect accordingly?

Comment: It's exactly what i want to do , but I still cannot figure out how , how can i edit it in the security.yml ?

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1 and Answer 2 : you have to use a LoginHandler : http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/

Answer 1 : use the security token passed as an argument to the handler to get your User, then retrieve it's company.

Answer 2 : choose your redirect response depending the company.